# How to make WinForms chart control primary Y axis to be drawn on both sides of the chart?

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

Y axis and its level labels are only drawn on the left by default while the right side appears unbordered and unlabelled. How to make them to be duplicated on the right side?[image]

Comment: I believe this should answer your question : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458791/ms-chart-control-two-y-axis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Primary Y-Axis can't be duplicated to draw in the right side. You have to use Secondary Y-Axis for that.

```
chart1.ChartAreas[ChartName].AxisY2.Enabled = AxisEnabled.True;
```

Enabling this duplicates the primary axis values in the right side.