# Creating bar + line chart with dual axis MVC4 .NET C# in controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, charts

Trying to create a chart in my controller (not in the view) that contains both a bar and a line chart with 2 y-axis.

Here's an example of what I'm looking to do...
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Flex/Chart/MultipleAxisChart.htm

Right now, I've been trying to use Microsofts System.Web.Helpers.Chart library, but it doesn't seem to support this functionality. Any help/ recommendations will be much appreciated! Anything that works will be given answer. Thanks!

Comment: Already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458791/ms-chart-control-two-y-axis)