# MS Chart multiple Y- Axes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, mschart

Is there a way to create a 2 Y axes for one chart.

It seem to be impossible adding more than 2 axes on the same graph.

Any clue ?.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This should help,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458791/ms-chart-control-two-y-axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should download the [mschart samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Samples-Environments-for-b01e9c61) from microsoft ... and look at

> Chart features -> Axes -> Multiple Y axes

[image]

here the code extract from it

```
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
...

if(checkBoxUseMultipleYAxis.Checked)
{
    // Set custom chart area position
    Chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].Position = new ElementPosition(25,10,68,85);
    Chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].InnerPlotPosition = new ElementPosition(10,0,90,90);

    // Create extra Y axis for second and third series
    CreateYAxis(Chart1, Chart1.ChartAreas["Default"], Chart1.Series["Series2"], 13, 8);
    CreateYAxis(Chart1, Chart1.ChartAreas["Default"], Chart1.Series["Series3"], 22, 8);
}
else
{
    // Set default chart areas
    Chart1.Series["Series2"].ChartArea = "Default";
    Chart1.Series["Series3"].ChartArea = "Default";

    // Remove newly created series and chart areas
    while(Chart1.Series.Count > 3)
    {
        Chart1.Series.RemoveAt(3);
    }
    while(Chart1.ChartAreas.Count > 1)
    {
        Chart1.ChartAreas.RemoveAt(1);
    }

    // Set default chart area position to Auto
    Chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].Position.Auto = true;
    Chart1.ChartAreas["Default"].InnerPlotPosition.Auto = true;
}

...

/// <summary>
/// Creates Y axis for the specified series.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="chart">Chart control.</param>
/// <param name="area">Original chart area.</param>
/// <param name="series">Series.</param>
/// <param name="axisOffset">New Y axis offset in relative coordinates.</param>
/// <param name="labelsSize">Extra space for new Y axis labels in relative coordinates.</param>
public void CreateYAxis(Chart chart, ChartArea area, Series series, float axisOffset, float labelsSize)
{
    // Create new chart area for original series
    ChartArea areaSeries = chart.ChartAreas.Add("ChartArea_" + series.Name);
    areaSeries.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    areaSeries.BorderColor = Color.Transparent;
    areaSeries.Position.FromRectangleF(area.Position.ToRectangleF());
    areaSeries.InnerPlotPosition.FromRectangleF(area.InnerPlotPosition.ToRectangleF());
    areaSeries.AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
    areaSeries.AxisX.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
    areaSeries.AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
    areaSeries.AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
    areaSeries.AxisY.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
    areaSeries.AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
    areaSeries.AxisY.IsStartedFromZero = area.AxisY.IsStartedFromZero;

    series.ChartArea = areaSeries.Name;

    // Create new chart area for axis
    ChartArea areaAxis = chart.ChartAreas.Add("AxisY_" + series.ChartArea);
    areaAxis.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    areaAxis.BorderColor = Color.Transparent;
    areaAxis.Position.FromRectangleF(chart.ChartAreas[series.ChartArea].Position.ToRectangleF());
    areaAxis.InnerPlotPosition.FromRectangleF(chart.ChartAreas[series.ChartArea].InnerPlotPosition.ToRectangleF());

    // Create a copy of specified series
    Series seriesCopy = chart.Series.Add(series.Name + "_Copy");
    seriesCopy.ChartType = series.ChartType;
    foreach(DataPoint point in series.Points)
    {
        seriesCopy.Points.AddXY(point.XValue, point.YValues[0]);
    }

    // Hide copied series
    seriesCopy.IsVisibleInLegend = false;
    seriesCopy.Color = Color.Transparent;
    seriesCopy.BorderColor = Color.Transparent;
    seriesCopy.ChartArea = areaAxis.Name;

    // Disable grid lines & tickmarks
    areaAxis.AxisX.LineWidth = 0;
    areaAxis.AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
    areaAxis.AxisX.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
    areaAxis.AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = false;
    areaAxis.AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
    areaAxis.AxisY.IsStartedFromZero = area.AxisY.IsStartedFromZero;

    // Adjust area position
    areaAxis.Position.X -= axisOffset;
    areaAxis.InnerPlotPosition.X += labelsSize;
}
...
```